# How does this popup appear and disappear after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It can be a basic question, but I'm in a starting stage of html,CSS and js.

When I click on the downvote I get a popup saying "vote down requires 125 reputation" which is awesome. I want this to be included in my site. I'm not expecting a complete solution for this. Just tell me the idea behind the popup appearing and disappearing after a while. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to create a HTML element that will display the popup message, so for example :

```
<div id="popUp" style="display: none;"> Popup Message </div>
```

You'll then need to attach an `onclick` or jQuery `click` event to some action or DOM element on your page. So if you want the user to see the popup after clicking a particular element on the page, i.e. a button. Then assign the `click` event to that particular element.

So the JS function might look like this :

```
// where #element is the HTML element you want to assign the click event to
$( "#element" ).click(function() {
   $( "#popUp" ).show(); 
   setTimeout(function() {
      $( "#popUp" ).hide();
    }, 2000);
});
```

So a few things are happening here when the `click` event fires: the interval is set for however many milliseconds needed, the element is shown by changing the CSS of the element to `display: block` within the `show();` function, then the interval is cleared using `clearInterval` and the element is hidden.

I hope this gives you a reasonable idea of the concept.

Comment: I think you should change your code to use setTimeout instead, it'll save one line of code!

Comment: Not really - as `setTimeout` has a similar opposite function of `clearTimeout` to clear previously stored timer values which I would employ for completeness. So what's the difference?

Comment: Actually I just realized your code never shows the popup, because you are clearing the setInterval immediately... You have to call clearInterval in the setInterval callback function in this case. And if you wanna use setTimeout, then you don't need to call clearTimeout because you would only want to call it when you don't want your callback to be executed which is not what we want.

Comment: Quite right Sir! I've changed the function accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this effect using simple `setTimeout` when calling function that is responsible for closing growl. Basic usage:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //Here goes function that is responsible for hiding growl 
}, 4000);
```

Basically what it does, it's calling a function after given time in miliseconds (in this case is 4000 ms which is 4s).

If you are using Bootstrap you can look at this plugin: http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/ 
It's working right out of the box